# SimpleForm::Components::Typeahead - preloading vs. server-side?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead.js

Hi is there a way to use this with a remote call to the server? Currently I have it working perfectly but only with preloaded data, e.g.

```
typeahead: User.all.pluck(:email)
```

Might get a bit cumbersome with lots of results at some point, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Use `remote`.

Here is the doc: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js#remote

In it's simplest form, this could be something like:

```
$('#input').typeahead([{
    remote: 'https://twitter.com/accounts?q=%QUERY'
}]);
```

... but make sure to read the docs, especially re. `filter`.

Comment: Thanks but how would I write the erb for this in the view using Simple Form?